# nginx cant't serve files correctly when deploy a django project with nginx and uwsgi on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

When I deploy a django project follow this tutorial:[http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html?highlight=django
when I done the step **Basic nginx test**, after i type taopinpin.cn/media/media.png, the page response denied like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3pO5.png)

and my project like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/criiS.png)
mysite_nginx.conf file is :

```
upstream django {
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
}
server {
    listen      8000;
    server_name  taopinpin.cn;

    charset     utf-8;

    client_max_body_size   75M;


    location /media  {
        alias /root/mysite/media;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /root/mysite/static;
    }
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass    django;
        inlcude       /root/mysite/mysite/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

I don't know where get an error, can you help me debug it ? Thank you a lot.

Comment: At least there is a typo in `inlcude /root/mysite/mysite/uwsgi_params;`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your *mysite_nginx.conf*:

```
upstream cluster {
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
} 

server {
    listen      8000;
    server_name  taopinpin.cn;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size   75M;

    location / {
         uwsgi_pass cluster;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
         include /root/mysite/mysite/uwsgi_params;
         uwsgi_modifier1 30;
         proxy_set_header HTTP_AUTHORIZATION $http_authorization;
         proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
         proxy_redirect  off;
         uwsgi_read_timeout 900;
     }

     location /media  {
         alias /root/mysite/media;
     }

     location /static {
         alias /root/mysite/static;
     }

     location ~* ^.+\.(js|css)$ {
         access_log off; log_not_found off;
     }

}
```

and then in your `/root/mysite/mysite/uwsgi_params` (verify that file indeed exists):

```
uwsgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
uwsgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
uwsgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
uwsgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
uwsgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
uwsgi_param PATH_INFO $document_uri;
uwsgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;
uwsgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
uwsgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
uwsgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
uwsgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
```

Run `nginx -t` to verify your syntax is valid.

Run `service nginx reload` or `/etc/init.d/nginx reload`

Create directory `/root/mysite/logs` and make it writable by
   `sudo mkdir /root/mysite/logs`

Then restart uwsgi - adjust `youruser` and `yourproject` to fit your specs:

```
   uwsgi --socket :8001 --module yourproject.wsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid youruser --gid youruser  --master --processes 6 --threads 3 --stats 127.0.0.1:9191 --daemonize=/root/mysite/logs/uwsgi.log
```

Based on your image your nginx server cannot serve your media files in
`/root/mysite/media` - give the nginx user ownership over it
If your user in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf is

```
user    www-data;
```

then do:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /root/mysite/media
```

- nginx user, which may be not the root user, has to have access to this directory.

Comment: can i change www-data to root? Thank you a lot.

Comment: It has to be same user as the one in your `nginx.conf` - you can, but then you may create certain vulnerabilities.Welcome.

Comment: I have done what you said : sudo chown www-data:www-data /root/mysite/media  But it is also can't work . I am so confused .

Comment: In your nginx.conf there has to be a line `error_log` - open that file and see what error message you have there. If not configured - configure it so you can see the error in the log and then restart nginx and uwsgi

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors here. `root` and `alias` are not the same thing and actually are totally unnecessary here anyway. You should specify root once, outside the location directives. They will inherit it from the server directive anyway and your are basically doing the same thing.

```
upstream django {
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
}
server {
    listen      8000;
    server_name  taopinpin.cn;
    root /root/mysite;       # you should really use a standard location, like /var/www
    charset     utf-8;

client_max_body_size   75M;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
}
location @proxy {
    inlcude       /root/mysite/mysite/uwsgi_params; # is this correct? Mine is in /etc/nginx
    uwsgi_pass    django;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have an typo in `inlcude` while it should be `include`.

Based on your [screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/criiS.png), you are running your application as user `root`, and your application is installed at directory `~/mysite`, this will be `/root/mysite` for user `root`, however when nginx is running using user name `www-data`, the `/root/mysite` is not accessible unless you are running everything with `sudo`. **Using `root` or running app with `sudo` is not a good practice.**

The `uwsgi_params` by default is installed in `/etc/nginx/`, and usually you don't need to specify the directory unless yours is not located in `etc/nginx/`.

There is a lack of definition of where the web root directory is in your nginx configuration, if you defined a web root directory `root /root/mysite`, then the location directives for `location /media` and `location /static` seems to be rather redundant and necessary.

With all the things that I mentioned above, here is the configuration that it should works for user `root` and assuming you also change the user setting at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` from `user www-data` to `user root`. **Again not recommended.**

```
upstream django {
  server 127.0.0.1:8001;
}
server {
  listen 8000;
  server_name taopinpin.cn;    #check your /etc/hostname setting
  root /root/mystie;    #this need to be change if it is not running by root
  charset utf-8;

  client_max_body_size   75M;

  location / {
    include uwsgi_params;    #make sure uwsgi_params exist at /etc/nginx/
    uwsgi_pass    django;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks！But how can i edit location of  media  and static？

Comment: If you point your web root root/mysite as /, then root/mysite/mdidia is already means /media, you don't need that alias setting. Read [nginx alias](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for more details.